# How do I tell which Subversion repository I'm working with?

Tags: svn

I have several projects spread across different repositories. Sometimes I forget which repository each project is stored in. Is there a command line argument for svn that shows the source repository for the working copy in the current directory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`svn info` should tell you everything you need to know.